# {exception=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing}

Tags: java, xml, maven, security

In Java 1.6, we can't find XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET. So I used XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING for secure coding.

When I run our maven project on server, I got this error message {exception=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing}](http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing%7D)

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're using an XML parser or XSLT processor that doesn't recognise this property - very likely because the software was released before the property was invented.

This property is designed to handle some security risks that are actually very unlikely to be a real issue in any normal workload. Using old software like JDK 1.6 is a much bigger security risk.